# Sum numbers in cell containing text without spaces

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I have done extensive research on SO and google but not coming up with a solution.
While this question may have been asked earlier, my situation is slightly different

The function works fine if there is a space between the text and numbers. However, does not work if there aren't any spaces.

```
Function SumNumbers(rngS As Range, Optional strDelim As String = " ") As Double
Dim xNums As Variant, lngNum As Long
xNums = Split(rngS, strDelim)
For lngNum = LBound(xNums) To UBound(xNums) Step 1
    SumNumbers = SumNumbers + Val(xNums(lngNum))
Next lngNum
End Function
```

My cell data looks like this: **su9m11w11.5th8**

I tried adding an alphabet array, but had no luck. Help is welcome.

```
strDelim = Array("F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "U")
```

Comment: What is your desired output here? Also, could there ever be negative numbers, say: `5xyz-10abc7`?

Comment: @JvdV I want to skip the alphabets and sum the numbers. So in this example, my output should be 39.5

Comment: no negative numbers at this time. But i'd guess, if the sum is successful, negatives will be deducted from the sum automatically correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, depening on your data, you could try:

```
Sub Test()

Dim StrIn As String: StrIn = "su9m11w11.5th8"
Debug.Print SumDigits(StrIn)

End Sub    

Function SumDigits(str As String) As Double

With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "[a-z]+"
    SumDigits = Application.Evaluate(.Replace(str, "+") & ".0")
End With

End Function
```

Here I used a regular expression to substitute all the lowercase characters ranging a-z for a "+". The resulting string then can be evaluated to return the sum.

---

EDIT:

Another way could be to use a regular expression that will return all the possible (negative) numbers, and sum those:

```
Function SumDigits(str As String) As Double

With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?"
    If .Test(str) Then
        For Each Match In .Execute(str)
            SumDigits = SumDigits + Match
        Next
    End If
End With
```

---

EDIT 2:

To return an average we should capture the amount of matching substrings and devide the sum by that count:

```
Function SumDigits(str As String, Optional avg As Boolean) As Double

With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?"
    If .Test(str) Then
        Set Matches = .Execute(str)
        For Each Match In Matches
            SumDigits = SumDigits + Match
        Next
        If avg Then SumDigits = SumDigits / Matches.Count
    End If
End With

End Function
```

Call using `Debug.Print SumDigits(StrIn, True)` instead.

Comment: the function works correctly. can you please explain the method as I am unfamiliar with that approach. would like to understand it. Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: If not asking for too much, is there a way to use the same function to get an average?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a VBA function to produce either the sum or the average of your embedded numbers... and it handles negatives as well. And this is pure Excel VBA with no references to outside libraries:

```
Function SumEmbeddedNumbers#(s$, Optional bAverage As Boolean)
    Dim i&, p&, max&, t&, pluses&
    Dim b() As Byte, res() As Byte
    Static keep() As Boolean

    Const VALS$ = "0123456789.-"
    
    If (Not Not keep) = 0 Then
        ReDim keep(0 To 255)
        For i = 1 To Len(VALS)
            keep(Asc(Mid$(VALS, i, 1))) = 1
        Next
    End If
    
    max = LenB(s)
    ReDim res(0 To max)
    b = StrConv(s, vbFromUnicode)
    For i = 0 To Len(s) - 1
        t = b(i)
        If keep(t) Then
            res(p) = t
            p = p + 1
        Else
            If p Then
                If res(p - 1) <> 43 Then
                    res(p) = 43
                    pluses = pluses + 1
                    p = p + 1
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
    SumEmbeddedNumbers = Evaluate(Left$(StrConv(res, vbUnicode), p))
    If bAverage Then SumEmbeddedNumbers = SumEmbeddedNumbers / (pluses + 1)
End Function
```

---

```
MsgBox SumEmbeddedNumbers("su9m11w11.5th8")          '<---displays: 39.5
MsgBox SumEmbeddedNumbers("su9m11w11.5th8", True)    '<---displays: 9.875
```